# Cannot access administrative share on Windows 7 from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, network-shares

so I have a Windows 7 PC in a workgroup mode, with couple of local users. Both these users belong to administrators group. I have been accessing administrative shares on that W7 machine for a long time, from Windows 8.1 aswell.

I have new laptop now, from which I cannot access admin shares. I get access denied. When I type wrong password I get password is incorrect.

I have tried LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy regedit which did not help.

What else should I do? I *can* access admin share on the 8.1 machine FROM the W7 machine, but not vice versa.

Comment: What research have you done? Like this...[Why can't I connect to other PCs?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/cant-connect-other-pcs)

Comment: Like I can connect to non administrative shares from that PC, or I can connect to administrative shares from other PCs, so there is nothing wrong with the network itself.

Comment: That would be an important detail to add to your question. In that case, it is pointing to the Windows 7 share security not allowing it. Have you looked at the permissions of that share to verify it includes the new laptop?

Comment: I use the same user to access it which works from other PCs. I am not aware of any other permissions which would filter by source machine name.

Comment: You said it is a new computer. Maybe there is a security policy that doesn't recognize the computer (not the user account).

Comment: It's a workgroup, there are no policies involved, at least that I'm aware of.

Comment: You checked all the suggestions in the article I linked in my first comment? If not, try them. If you have, I'm out of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So, in fact it was the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry key which needed to be added to Windows *7* machine. It also needed a reboot. Even then it didn't work. Then I disabled Admin Approval Mode for all admins on Windows 7 machine. Then I reenabled it, and it stayed working.

Why it wasn't needed before I don't know.